# Connect to a windows process in php

Tags: php

How can I connect to a process like the calculator provided by windows or access my page whenever I start up the windows.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Please add more detail. "Connect to a process" can mean many things

Comment: Frankly I want to access an .exe from my system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you just want to start a Windows program within your script. This would be something like

```
<?php
    system('c:\path\to\exe\file\program.exe -param1 -param2');
?>
```

Comment: They would be the parameters you are passing to the application, if there are any. I can't think of any examples as Windows doesn't really have many CLI apps. Do note that you will be running said command on the server, not on the client.